# Стоит ли сейчас знать Flash и ActionScript веб-разработчику?

Tags: css3, flash, html5, javascript, actionscript

Добрый вечер. Хочу спросить Ваше мнение - стоит ли сейчас знать Flash и ActionScript веб-разработчику? Или не стоит на это уже тратить время и делать похожие задачи на HTML5 + CSS3 + JS? Спрашиваю, потому как еще иногда попадаются заказчики, которые просят сделать им сайт с использованием технологии Flash. Очень интересно услышать Ваше мнение!

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в FLash особо, но точно, не всё, что может флеш, можно сделать на JS. Посмотрите игру "Легенда".

Comment: поверьте AS вам не помешает, кругозор в языках программирование увеличите, плюс со знанием AS вы можете пойти во Flex разработчики и писать богатые клиентские апликации, которые куда сложнее пишутся на js

Comment: Флеш умер!гугл и эппл отказались от него в пользу html5.
Так что не стоит тратить время на изучение мертвой технологии.

Comment: а игры в соц. сетях тоже умерли?

Comment: Я бы так быстро не записывал его в мёртвые. Делать просто сайты, к примеру блоги или визитки на флеше - да, невыгодно и глупо. А вот игры, игровые приложения - вполне.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/139928/ просто вспомнилось (мнение автора может не совпадать с моим)
@deniz а ты чего такой дерзкий?)

Comment: Спс, да приходится иногда заголовки сочинять)

Comment: @deniz Надеюсь, что скоро за такие заголовки будут привлекать к ответственности в соответствии с КоАП и УК.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Шесть лет в web-е. Флеша не знаю, и никогда дискомфорта от этого не испытывал. Как правило, работа с флеш, это скорее к дизайнерам. А у кодеров и без флеша целый зоопарк технологий, php, html, js, css, sql итд.

К тому-же флеш потихоньку уходит из веба, думаю через пару лет его вообще не останется...

Comment: Солидарен с Вами, но на днях попался заказчик, который говорит - хочу сайт с Flash и все, хоть ты тресни, не могу его переубедить ;-( Поэтому решил спросить у сообщества стоит ли начать интенсивное изучение или отказаться от геморройного заказа?

Comment: @eprivalov1 Ну мне кажется что от этого заказа вам в любом случае лучше отказаться, далеко не факт что вам сразу удастся на незнакомой технологии сделать достойный продукт, чтобы потом не краснеть)))

Comment: Да уж, согласен с Вами, откажусь пожалуй от греха подальше.

Comment: >думаю через пару лет его вообще не останется...

с первого подобного заявления прошла не одна пара лет, и ещё пройдёт не одна, пока оно сбудиться

Comment: @Spectre Apple и Google убрали флеш из IOS и Android соответственно. Из Linux флеш практически "убрался" сам. Остается только Windows, а Microsoft проталкивает Silverlight (Или как там эта их технология называется?) В общем делайте выводы...

Comment: @павел-вершинин что значит из линукса флеш убрался сам, это как?

Comment: Скорее всего имеется ввиду то, что в Линуксе флеш геморройно установить....

Comment: @rnd_d Adobe отказался от поддержки флеш под Linux (Извиняюсь ссылки на источник не будет, сейчас в отъезде, GPRS не располагает к активному гуглению. Посмотрите на Хабре там вроде было).
И последняя версия флеш под Linux по сути непригодна, постоянно крашится. Приходится либо откатывать флеш на одну из прежних версий, либо использовать Google Chrome (Не Chromium, а именно Chrome) у которого свой нормальный флеш плагин.

Answer (score 3):

Я считаю, что если есть талант к рисованию, то очень даже стоит выучить Flash и AS. Ибо создав качественную игру в соц. сетях можно заработать кучу денег. Или даже можно хорошую онлайн игру сделать. А сайты на флеш по мне - это гавно, попробуйте убедить в этом заказчика)

Answer (score 2):

Экшнскрипт - родственник джаваскрипта, они оба построены на основе экмаскрипт.
Тоесть, зная экшнскрипт, разработчик с легкостью переключится на ХТМЛ5, а учить его нет смысла

Comment: Я с Вами согласен ActionScript и JavaScript очень похожи.. Поэтому для человека, который знает JavaScript, изучить ActionScript не составит огромного труда. Другое дело рисовать в Adobe Flash CS5...